# flexDirection has no effect on Text element in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I need some text to wrap differently based on the screen width. `flexDirection` appears to have no effect here:

```
<Text style={{
  flexDirection: breakpoint ? "column" : "row"
}>
  <Text>Choose </Text>
  <Text>your workout</Text>
</Text>
```

Can Text elements not apply this style?

Comment: replace main ```Text```  with ```View```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply flexDirection and you are missing a close '}' in style check this

change

```
<Text style={{
  flexDirection: breakpoint ? "column" : "row"
}>
  <Text>Choose </Text>
  <Text>your workout</Text>
</Text>
```

to

```
<View style={{
  flexDirection: breakpoint ? "column" : "row"
}}>
  <Text>Choose </Text>
  <Text>your workout</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Working Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@jamesweblondon/sadistic-milkshake